# pandoc Include files filter in haskell

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I am using this haskell pandoc include files filter

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
-- includes.hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

doInclude :: Block -> IO Block
doInclude cb@(CodeBlock (id, classes, namevals) contents) =
  case lookup "include" namevals of
       Just f     -> return . (CodeBlock (id, classes, namevals)) =<< readFile f
       Nothing    -> return cb
doInclude x = return x

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter doInclude
```

with the following code snippet in markdown

```
~~~~ {include="tasks/mdbook.js"}
~~~~
```

This does in fact include the file into the markdown however I would like it to also include the code formatting for example

````
```js
file content here
```
````

How can I update the above haskell code to acomplish this? with something like

```
~~~~ {code="tasks/mdbook.js", format="js"}
~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `include` filter preserves all `classes` of code block, you can include file contents and apply code formatting to it simply with this:

```
~~~~ {.javascript include="tasks/mdbook.js"}
~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the problem you're trying to solve is to have a markdown document that refers to some piece of code and you would like to avoid copy-pasting the code into the document and having a nightmare of synchronizing the two versions by hand. So you've tried to solve the problem by including the source files into the markdown document via a filter.

I solved the same problem in a different way. I kept all (relevant) source code in the markdown document and wrote a tool which extract all the source code. My particular use-case was that I was writing slides for lectures and every time I compiled my slides I also extracted the code and made sure it compiled. I also bundled all the code into a zip archive for the convenience of my students.

My tool is available here:
https://github.com/josefs/CodeExtract

You can write code blocks like these:

```
~~~ {.haskell file="Hello.hs"}
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
~~~
```

When running a document containing such code blocks through my little tool it will generate a file `Hello.hs` containing the code in the block.

There is also a more advanced feature supporting several snippets of code which can end up in the same document. For example you can have two code blocks like these:

```
~~~ {.haskell template="Hello.hs.tmpl" var="mainfkn"}
main = putStrLn str
~~~

~~~ {.haskell template="Hello.hs.tmpl" var="misc"}
str = "Hello World!"
~~~
```

And then a template file, `Hello.hs.tmpl` like the following (it uses the same template format as pandoc):

```
~~~
module Main where
$mainfkn$
$misc$
~~~
```

It will generate a file `Hello.hs` containing the template file but with the variable substituted with the corresponding code block in the markdown file. It's very handy.

I hope you find my tool useful, though I realize it might not address your particular problem.

Comment: Hi svenningsson, thanks for the response but I need it to go the other way around. I do not want to keep the source code in markdown files as I would loses all my nice IDE features. Is there no way to add characters to the beginning of the IO Block in haskell?

Comment: Fair enough. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is to update the attributes of the code block. Here's what you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
-- includes.hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

doInclude :: Block -> IO Block
doInclude cb@(CodeBlock (id, classes, namevals) contents) =
  case lookup "include" namevals of
       Just f     -> do
         let newAttrs = filter ((/= "include") . fst) namevals ++ [("code",f), ("format","js")]
         return . (CodeBlock (id, classes, newAttrs)) =<< readFile f
       Nothing    -> return cb
doInclude x = return x

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter doInclude
```

Change the code for `newAttr` as you see fit.

Comment: this does not seem to compile. Will this code update the code block? It looks like it will add the code, and format values to the attributes array which is not what I am trying to achieve. in the .md file I would like to specify the code, format and have the filter add the necessary characters to the beginning of the returned code block as in '''js (readfile code here) '''

Comment: First error was lexical error in string/character literal at character '\n' I think it was due to a missing " after the "include after fixing that it now wont compile with the following error parse error on input `return'

Comment: I didn't want to make it too easy for you :-) I've updated the code so that it typechecks. The changes are: the missing " that you noticed, and then the 'do' after the 'Just f ->' pattern.
I haven't tested the code though.

Comment: this does not seem to do what I wanted. I do not want to update the attributes i want to prepend the string "'''(format)" and append the string "'''" to the "contents" which should be the read file.. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow but are you asking for something like this (replace your line beginning with "return" with this):   
`file <- readFile f`  
`let n = "```js\n" ++ file ++ "```\n"`  
`return (CodeBlock (id, classes, namevals) n)`

Comment: Sorry about the messed up formatting. There should be line breaks in there instead of the spaces between the code blocks.